# How to self register customer for community from force.com site

Tags: force.com-sites, customer-community

I've created a force.com site &  for register and login we using community.

I'm working on for  self register a customer from force.com site.

I'm using **CommunitiesSelfReg** page on my force.com site and try to register, but it gives me error.

> The site is not enabled for registration.

What is the workaround here.

What is the use of **sitelogin &  Siteregister** standard pages of site. where it will be used?

I've to only used standard Register & login pages of community. Is this correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, have you enabled 'Allow external users to self-register'?

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_customize_selfreg_page.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Comment: YEs. I've enabled  'Allow external users to self-register'. still showing error.